# *** mixed implicit and normal rules. Stop

Tags: makefile, glibc

I needed to use a older version of glibc to compile some software (2.12 specifically). So, I downloaded glibc from https://ftp.gnu.org and tried to compile it. But it gives me the following error:

> Makefile:235: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.

And, following is the line 235 of Makefile:
   `$(objpfx)stubs ../po/manual.pot $(objpfx)stamp%:`
How can I fix this? I'm using gcc-4.8.5 in RHEL7.3.

Comment: The version of GCC is not relevant.  What is relevant is the version of GNU make.  Also you should show the text at line 235 of the Makefile.  However, likely your version of GNU make is between 3.82 and 4.0.  In 3.82 the make parser was modified to flag an error on syntax which was always not allowed but which wasn't originally caught as an error.  Some makefiles contained this syntax.  In GNU make 4.1, the syntax was allowed again but with a warning so that people using older broken makefiles could still build.

Comment: You either need to get an older (before 3.82) or newer (4.1 or newer) version of GNU make, or else get a newer version of glibc where this issue has been fixed, or else edit your glibc makefiles to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

from:

```
$(objpfx)stubs $../po/manual.pot $(objpfx)stamp%:
        $(make-target-directory)
        touch $@
```

change to:

```
$(objpfx)stubs:
        $(make-target-directory)
        touch $@
$../po/manual.pot:
        $(make-target-directory)
        touch $@
$(objpfx)stamp%:
        $(make-target-directory)
        touch $@
```